# How can I import Python script at Pybind11 when C++ and Python files are not at the same folder?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Example of Files directory:

```
base-->
      src_c-->
              Example.cpp (imports myPyExample.py)
      src_python-->
              myPyExample.py
```

and I'd like to import python script using pybind11

What is the way to do it? (found only examples where both are under the same folder)

Answer (score 0):

This may be overly simple, but you could just use '../src_python/myPyExample.py'

Another solution would be to have some function which returns the absolute path to 'base' then use it to create an absolute path to 'src_python'

like this:
`path = getBaseDirectory() + "/src_python/myPyExample.py"`